# framework not found Exception in iOS

Tags: ios

I am adding a third party framework to my app! Under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries I added the third party frameworks. But when I run I get the following error:

```
ld: framework not found RUA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Check the `BuildSettings->SearchPaths->FrameworkSearchPaths`.